# How to bundle JS and CSS file independently with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I have a few JS and SCSS files. I need Webpack 4 to bundle each JS entry to one JS file and each SCSS entry to one CSS file. The JS files don't import the SCSS files. I try to do it with the following `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    scriptFoo: './src/js/scriptFoo.js',
    scriptBar: './src/js/scriptBar.js',
    // ...
    styleBaz: './src/css/styleBaz.scss',
    styleBaq: './src/css/styleBaq.scss'
    // ...
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css'
    })
  ]
};
```

It works fine, Webpack puts the compiled files to the `dist` directory. But it also creates an excess dummy JS file for each SCSS file in the `dist` directory:

```
webpack.config.js
src/
  js/
    scriptFoo.js
    scriptBar.js
    ...
  css/
    styleBaz.scss
    styleBaq.scss
    ...
dist/
  scriptFoo.js
  scriptBar.js
  ...
  styleBaz.css
  styleBaz.js // Excess
  styleBaq.css
  styleBaq.js // Excess
  ...
```

How to make Webpack not to create the excess JS files?

Comment: in theory each css should be included where it is being used, or if it is global inside your entrypoint. Webpack creating dummy js when css is an entry point is a known bug, which has not been fixed yet. That depends on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [ignore-emit-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/mrbar42/ignore-emit-webpack-plugin) Webpack plugin to not create the excess file. First install it by running in a console:

```sh
npm install --save-dev ignore-emit-webpack-plugin
```

Then add it to your Webpack configuration:

```js
const IgnoreEmitPlugin = require('ignore-emit-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new IgnoreEmitPlugin(['styleBaz.js', 'styleBaq.js']) // Or simply: new IgnoreEmitPlugin(/^style.*\.js$/)
  ]
};
```

Comment: This is a ridiculous problem and solution.   Not your fault but just the way it is... Webpack has had this issue for many years now.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes, Webpack has its logic that explains everything (even though it's not intuitive). In general, Webpack combines input JavaScript files into output JavaScript files, that's why JS is always emitted; it can be extended with loaders (components that convert non-JS files to JS) and plugins (that do different things like extracting CSS into separate output files or deleting output files). Actually converting SCSS to CSS from individual entries isn't what Webpack is designed for, but since the rest of my project is built using Webpack, I've decided to use Webpack for this too.

Answer (score 0):

It is because for each property in the entry object ,The js file is created in output destinations.

`output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },`

Webpack creating dummy js when css is an entry point is a known bug, which has not been fixed yet.

Also having multiple entry files in the entry configuration will also affect treeshaking capabilties

Comment: Thank you. You explained why the dummy files are created but you didn't answer the question (how to not create them).