# Webpack - css - extract to multiple files?

Tags: vue.js, sass, compilation, webpack-5, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm on Webpack 5, compiling mostly Vue sfc sass styles, and currently I achieved to extract all the css styles to a single css bundle using [`mini-css-extract-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-css-extract-plugin).

Obviously this bundle has grown in size and consequently the download stars taking s bit too much time, so I'm trying to split it in smaller chunks to parallelize the download.

Found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677070/webpack-mini-css-extract-plugin-output-multiple-css-files-on-single-entry), but the user managed to solve the problem using multiple entry points (which I want to avoid since the project is a spa (am I wrong?)) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65834627/3030926) which suggest to configure `mini-css-extract-plugin` `filename` property to use a function instead of a string, but it seems not working since every chunk passed to the function seems having the same name/id, maybe due starting from a single entry point?

```js
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    // example
    filename: (x) => {
        console.log(x.chunk.name);
        console.log("=====");
        return "css/main.[contenthash].css";
    }
}),
```

```
> webpack-demo@1.0.0 build
> webpack

main
=====
main
=====
main
=====
main
=====

...
```

How can I split the outputted css bundle to multiple files?